# Movement through "Wall of Sand"

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement

> You conjure up a wall of swirling sand on the ground at a point you can see within range. You can make the wall up to 30 feet long, 10 feet high, and 10 feet thick, and it vanishes when the spell ends. It blocks line of sight but not movement. **A creature is blinded while in the wall’s space and must spend 3 feet of movement for every 1 foot it moves there**

So how much movement exactly do I need per square? I just can't figure out the math. Is it harder to move through than difficult terrain?

Comment: how big are your squares?  5' or 10' on a side?

Comment: It is weird that they measured it in singular feet instead of multiples of 5 feet or in squares.  However, the math doesn't change - it's a ratio of 3:1, so you multiply by three.

Comment: @SouthpawHare Using a grid is an option from the DMG it is not the default.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## 3 Squares of Movement per Square

Assuming a 5ft/Square grid: Normal difficult terrain costs 2 Squares per square (AKA 2 feet of movement per 1 foot moved). Wall of Sand costs 3 feet per foot moved or 3 Squares per Square moved.

This is in effect doubly-difficult terrain, but it is notably NOT **Difficult Terrain** for the purposes of any class features, abilities or anything else.